# Prefix for MySQL tables in Ubuntu Home Server

Tags: server, mysql

So I have a question.

I am a new Ubuntu Server user. I have most of it set up and now I am setting up some different software so that I can have a development environment to develop my sites.

The problem that I am having is that I'm not sure what to put as my prefix for the mysql login and user name.

IE:
MySql Host, MySQL Username and MySQL Database.

I tried doing localhost_name for both Username and Database name. Neither worked. 
Any suggestions would be great!
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

During the installation of mysql-server you should have added a root password for the mysql account. This is what you should be using to configure the initial development databases.

For exmaple, If I had a wordpress site that I wanted to develop on. Then I could do the following.

1. Log into mysql: 

   `mysql -u root -p`
2. Create a new Wordpress DB 
   `create database wordpress;`
3. Add a user for wordpress 
   `grant all on wordpress.* to 'user' identified by 'password';`

Now you can log in to mysql using this new user and password, and enter the same credentials for whatever application you are using.

You can repeat this process for any database and any applicaiton stack, wordpress was just a simple example.